# In wordpress is it possible to force an image carousel to only start animating when the user views it?

Tags: wordpress, animation, carousel

I got an image carousel and it starts doing the carousel immediately when the page loads. I want it instead to do the carousel only when the user scrolls the page to it, i.e. when the user first starts to see it. The carousel has no option that allows this.

I'm thinking it's possible to do this by editing the javascript specific to this carousel animation, however I have no idea how to find this script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello mr. Bot, I don't have any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript observer i think